# get Id from the path in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

Following is my $routeProvider.when

```
.when("/products/:id",{
        templateUrl:"app/views/product.html",
        controller:"productController"
    })
```

I want to access the value of :id in the product controller.

Based on which i will populate product details.

the url is **/index.html#/products/3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$routeParams.id` in your controller.

Comment: This worked. But a bit confused on passing $routeParam. Whether it should be app.controller('productController', [$routeParams,function ($scope, $http) {}]); or app.controller('productController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {});

Comment: It's little strange but I use it like this:
`app.controller('productController', [$routeParams, $scope, $http, function ($routeParams, $scope, $http) { }]);`
Beware when using it parameters order is **important!**

Answer (score 2):

Inject [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) to your controller factory function.

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.id= $routeParams.id;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it in your controller with `$routeParams`

```
app.controller('productController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.productId = $routeParams.id;
};
```

Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

`$stateParams` are for custom [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 1):

## Use the $location service

To access any part of a path you need to use the $location service. It lets you use different parts of the url. For instance (From docs)

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

But what you want is this

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path = $location.path();
// => "/some/path"
```

This will return a string that is everything after the #

so then you can Use `slice` or some other JS function to get the part you need.

Best of luck